# Get the REBOOT permission in Android app

Tags: android

I'm writing a system update service that needs the REBOOT permission. From what I gather, adding it to the manifest is not enough - the app needs to be signed with the same key as the OS.

This will be possible on the actual device, since I will have that key, but what about the emulator? Is it possible to sign an app with the same key as the SDK/emulator or any other way to simulate it having the permission?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to run your own custom firmware on the emulator, so you control its signing key.

Comment: I will make my own build of the ROMs and try that. Is it then possible to sign the app as part of the Launch process in Eclipse, so I can quickly debug & modify, without using the File > Export > APK signing process?

Comment: @TomA: Beats me. I have never loaded custom firmware on the emulator, nor do I use Eclipse much.